# NodeJS - installing local module

Tags: node.js

`npm i /path/to/module/folder` will create a dependency for your project on **local module**
it creates a link to that folder as the docs says

> • **npm install < folder >**:
>
> Install the package in the directory as a symlink in the current
>   project. Its dependencies will be installed before it's linked. If
>    sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be
>   hoisted to the toplevel node_modules as they would for other types of
>   dependencies.

- there is a flag `--no-bin-links` that prevent creating links only to `bin's` files

***What i want is :*** is there a way to be able to make dependency on that local module by copy it not link it, so i can make changes and won't reflect on other projects until i manually `npm update my-local-module` it

***PS*** : from what i searched that was the default behavior of `npm install <folder>` but they changed it.

Comment: honestly you're probably better off just publishing a scoped package to NPM so you can reference the specific version. Using `0.0.*` version numbers is a good way to flag that a package is in development.

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks but the whole point is to work on my module offline :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a tarball from `your-local-module` with [npm-pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) and then install it offline using [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

`npm install <tarball file>`

> Install a package that is sitting on the filesystem. Note: if you just want to link a dev directory into your npm root, you can do this more easily by using **npm link**. The filename *must* use **.tar**, **.tar.gz**, or **.tgz** as the extension.