# How to move installed NODE module from one computer to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have limited network on one computer but can copy any file/folder to it.

On the second computer I have a full internet access and no restrictions and could successfully install a Node module.

How to bring installation (of one module) from second computer to first?

What folder/files and config needs to be copied in order to work without installation?

Comment: Ok, if I just copy the whole `node_modules` folder - would it work in another computer when I reference specific module or there are other settings needed?

Comment: Apparently, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592600/7393478), you can pack a module to a file, then install it somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to cherry pick one module only especially if it has multiple dependencies. Your best bet is probably copying the whole `node_modules` folder.

If you need one package only, a workaround would be making a new folder on the PC with internet, install the package and then just copying the `node_modules` folder to the PC without internet connection. No additional settings are needed (if we aren't talking about global packages).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy whole node_module folder bcz it's very big in size.

So the alternate and best option is you just copy your package.json file on second computer and re-install all node module again.

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to copy all node_modules from one system to another. What you can do is, copy `package.json` from one system to another and run command `npm install`.

Comment: "I have limited network on one computer but can copy any file/folder to it." - No internet, no `npm install`