# How can I migrate my installed npm packages between computers?

Tags: npm

I am totally new to NPM, trying to set it up on a non-internet PC based on an existing build machine's installed packages. In Nuget, there's a way to export everything I have installed which can then be copied and used as a nuget location... is there a way to do this in NPM as well, package everything up and reinstall on another machine?

Copying the entire cache folder(s) seems a blunt-force option... for some reason I have both `npm` and `npm-cache` in my local app-data folder and I am not sure of the distinction.

I had hoped there might be a way to regenerate all the package archive files from the cache somehow.

Comment: This link may be help you what exactly u want            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003813/how-to-move-installed-node-module-from-one-computer-to-another

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just want to move your packages from one PC to another PC that don't have an internet connection you can simply just copy paste the `node_modules` folder to the new PC that doesn't have the internet and if your new PC has an internet connection then just copy-paste the `package.json` & `package-lock.json` to the new folder and run `npm install` to install all required packages. But remember in both case you need to have NodeJS and NPM installed on the the new PC :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use yarn V3 (Berry) it packages the files up in compressed archives.
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry

Another option is compressing the entire project folder. this will make it faster to transfer to and from external drives so you can use the sneakernet.
https://serverfault.com/a/9743

Answer (score 0):

You should only copy `package.json` from one system to another and run command `npm install`

Comment: no internet access

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: My answer is only for Windows!**

I have tried it!

You can copy or pack to .zip file from this folder:

```
C:\Users\{Your Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and copy or unpack to the same position on other computers, then they got the same environment of npm.

You can test it by run this command below:

```
$ npm list -g
```